# Check if a pandas Series has at least one item greater than a value

Tags: python, pandas, series, membership, any

The following code will print True because the Series contains at least one element that is greater than 1. However, it seems a bit un-Pythonic. Is there a more Pythonic way to return True if a Series contains a number that is greater than a particular value?

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0.5, 2])
print True in (s > 1)          # True
```

Not only is the above answer un-Pythonic, it will sometimes return an incorrect result for some reason. For example:

```py
s = pd.Series([0.5])
print True in (s < 1)          # False
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) method to check if that condition is `True` at least for the one value:

```
In [36]: (s > 1).any()
Out[36]: True
```

Comment: How do you extend that operation to a set of columns so that it returns if there is at least one value greater than zero among all values?

Comment: @FedericoGentile do you mean something like `any(axis=1).any()`?  First, it'll be checked across all rows in your subset and will produce the Pandas Series. Second, you'll check series for any `True` values. If not you could provide an example in the comment or maybe better to ask a new question with all details.

Comment: I meant if I have a dataframe with 3 columns (A, B, C) and I want to check if there is at least a value grater than 0 in column A and B... one possible solution is to do this: (df.A > 1).any() and (df.B > 1).any(). Is there a nicer and elegant way to do it?

Comment: @FedericoGentile you could use something like `(df[['A', 'B', 'C']] > 1).any(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

`in` operator a.k.a `__contains__()` method checks if a specific value exists as an index in a Series.

```py
s = pd.Series([0.5], index=['a'])

'a' in (s > 1)          # True
'b' in s                # False
```

As a side note, `in` operator used on dataframes checks if a value exists as a column label.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns=['a'])
'a' in df               # True
'b' in df               # False
```

In other words, the fact that the `in` operator returns True or False has nothing to do with whether `(s > 1)` has any True values in it or not. In order to make the membership test work, the values must be accessed.

```py
True in (s < 1).values  # True
```

Reducing the values into a single boolean value (as suggested by @Anton Protopopov) is the canonical way to this task. Python's built-in `any()` function may be called as well.

```py
any(s > 1)              # False
s.gt(1).any()           # False

(s < 1).any()           # True
s.lt(1).any()           # True
```