# Pandas .any() vs. Python any() on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, any

What is the reason to prefer Pandas implementation of `.any()` instead of Python's builtin `any()` when used on a DataFrame?  Is there a performance reason to this, since Pandas DataFrames are column-major?  My hunch is perhaps the Pandas method is implemented in such a way that it is faster for column-based reads, in expectation.  Can anyone confirm?

Why this:

```
if df.any():
```

instead of this:

```
if any(df):
```

Comment: these do *two completely different things*

Comment: ah ok, could you please specify?  there is at least one answer on this website which states that Pandas suggests use their methods and not Python builtins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273980 I think a reasonable reader would conclude that these methods do pretty much the same thing (I confess that I made this assumption)

Comment: A bit related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75903308/19123103. Not the same because that one is about `in` while this one is about `any`.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I am wrong:

1. **Performance**: the methods of Pandas are highly optimized for operating on Pandas objects (C-level speed optimization).
2. **Handling NaN values**: NaN values are treated as `False`.
3. **Axis specification**: you can specify the axis along which to perform the method on.
4. **Different behavior**: `any(df)` checks the truthiness of the columns themselves, not the individual values within the DataFrame.
5. **Output is still a Series (or DF)**.
6. It ensures more **consistency** when working within the Pandas framework.

Comment: Pandas .any() method also allows for use of other Pandas style parameters within the call itself.

Answer (score 3):

These do two completely different things, so you cannot compare them directly. This is easily verifiable:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np, pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,2, size=(10,3)), columns=('a','b','c'))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  0  1  1
5  0  0  0
6  1  0  1
7  0  0  0
8  1  1  0
9  1  0  1

In [5]: df.any()
Out[5]:
a    True
b    True
c    True
dtype: bool

In [6]: any(df)
Out[6]: True
```

`pandas.DataFrame.any` is a method that does an "or" reduction operation across some dimension (by default, the 0th axis) which results in some `pandas.Series` object. In contrast, the built-in `any` takes an *iterable*, and does this reduction on an *iterable*. The result is always a `bool` object. When you iterate over a pandas dataframe, you iterate over the columns. So for the above `df`, the operation `any(df)` is equivalent to:

```
In [8]: list(df)
Out[8]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [9]: any(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[9]: True
```

Again, note, you can choose the axis for the `.any` method, like most methods in `pandas`:

```
In [10]: df.any(axis=1)
Out[10]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Note, if you worked with a `pd.Series`, which iterates over the values in the series, the operation would be (almost) the same:

```
In [12]: any(df['a'])
Out[12]: True

In [13]: all(df['a'])
Out[13]: False

In [14]: df['a'].any()
Out[14]: True

In [15]: df['a'].all()
Out[15]: False
```

Barring how in vanilla Python, `float('nan')` is treated as truthy, whereas in `pandas` by default, are *skipped*.

However, you should use the `pandas` methods for pandas data structures, because they are heavily optimized.